# Generate Maven "provided" dependency in pom.xml from Gradle "compileOnly"

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies, pom.xml

If I understand correctly, Gradle's `compileOnly` dependency corresponds to Gradle's older `provided`, and at the same time, Maven POM's `provided`. It works perfectly in the Gradle world.

But, `compileOnly` does not generate any `provided` dependency in `pom.xml` generated by `maven-publish`.

We are publishing a Maven artifact to Maven Central, using Gradle. We would like to declare `provided` explicitly in the published `pom.xml` from Gradle's `compileOnly`.

---

Does anyone know if there is any simple way to do that? Or, do we need to write our own Gradle scripting in :

```
publishing {
  publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
      pom {
         /* Our own Gradle scripting to declare provided dependencies. */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: JFYI, It didn't work: `components.java.addVariantsFromConfiguration(project.configurations.compileOnly) { it.mapToMavenScope("provided") }`

Answer (score 1):

I know we can tweak it by scripting dirty like below, but we basically don't want to "script" in `build.gradle` as far as possible.

```
publishing {
  publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
      pom {
        withXml {
          project.configurations.compileOnly.allDependencies.each { dependency ->
              asNode().dependencies[0].appendNode("dependency").with {
                it.appendNode("groupId", dependency.group)
                it.appendNode("artifactId", dependency.name)
                it.appendNode("version", dependency.version)
                it.appendNode("scope", "provided")
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think scripting is the way to go... you can create a method och pass the pom e.g

```
 publishing {
        publications {
            mavenDependencyList(MavenPublication) {
                fixDependencyScope(pom)
            }
        }
    }


void fixDependencyScope(pom) {
    pom.withXml {
        asNode().dependencies.'*'.findAll() {
            it.scope.text() == 'compileOnly' && project.configurations.compile.allDependencies.find { dep ->
                dep.name == it.artifactId.text()
            }
        }.each() {
            it.scope*.value = 'provided'
        }
    }
}
```